# Using json_encode() in PHP and JSON.parse() in JavaScript to read/write from/to a file

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, sorting

I'm using `json_encode()` in `PHP` to write an array into a file and after that I use `JSON.parse()` in `JavaScript` on the client side to read the json encoded file and pass it as an array to a sorting algorithm:

> - My json_encode() output file:
>     ["1","96","32","33","4","48","74","19","23","43","8","8","46","36","92","81","81","64","26","96","82","85","80","24","61","4","46","32","68","11","63","14","98","20","66","17","28","58","32","16","33","47","80","94","5","68","35","28","24","85","38","12","79","57","6","47","18","15","34","18","91","63","67","73","86","16","71","29","14","79","18","10","97","29","1","97","72","92","42","19","25","76","38","25","21","37"]
> - After using JSON.parse() I get my array back in a variabel `unsortedArray` with:
> - Index: 0
> - Value: 1,96,32,33,4,48,74,19,23,43,8,8,46,36,92,81,81,64,26,96,82,85,80,24,61,4,46,32,68,11,63,14,98,20,66,17,28,58,32,16,33,47,80,94,5,68,35,28,24,85,38,12,79,57,6,47,18,15,34,18,91,63,67,73,86,16,71,29,14,79,18,10,97,29,1,97,72,92,42,19,25,76,38,25,21,37

But when I put it through a sorting algorithm like for example Bublesort (I know it's not the best one) I get a strange output:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 10
            [3] => 11
            [4] => 12
            [5] => 14
            [6] => 14
            [7] => 15
            [8] => 16
            [9] => 16
            [10] => 17
            [11] => 18
            [12] => 18
            [13] => 18
            [14] => 19
            [15] => 19
            [16] => 20
            [17] => 21
            [18] => 23
            [19] => 24
            [20] => 24
            [21] => 25
            [22] => 25
            [23] => 26
            [24] => 28
            [25] => 28
            [26] => 29
            [27] => 29
            [28] => 32
            [29] => 32
            [30] => 32
            [31] => 33
            [32] => 33
            [33] => 34
            [34] => 35
            [35] => 36
            [36] => 37
            [37] => 38
            [38] => 38
            [39] => 4
            [40] => 4
            [41] => 42
            [42] => 43
            [43] => 46
            [44] => 46
            [45] => 47
            [46] => 47
            [47] => 48
            [48] => 5
            [49] => 57
            [50] => 58
            [51] => 6
            [52] => 61
            [53] => 63
            [54] => 63
            [55] => 64
            [56] => 66
            [57] => 67
            [58] => 68
            [59] => 68
            [60] => 71
            [61] => 72
            [62] => 73
            [63] => 74
            [64] => 76
            [65] => 79
            [66] => 79
            [67] => 8
            [68] => 8
            [69] => 80
            [70] => 80
            [71] => 81
            [72] => 81
            [73] => 82
            [74] => 85
            [75] => 85
            [76] => 86
            [77] => 91
            [78] => 92
            [79] => 92
            [80] => 94
            [81] => 96
            [82] => 96
            [83] => 97
            [84] => 97
            [85] => 98
        )
```

I call the function with the sorting algorithm and the input like this `bubleSort.apply(this, unsortedArray);`.

But as shown above it's not completely sorted, everything except the numbers 1 (just accidently in the right place), 4, 5, 6 and 8 is sorted, I don't understand why this is happening.

**Update:**

The `$jobRetParam` has all the results that comes from another page, it's an output of a JavaScript code being sent using `POST` to the site with this code:

```
$jobRetParam = $_REQUEST['results'];
```

The $allOutputVarPath variable is created here:

```
$allOutputVarPath = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($allOutputVar as $key => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 4) {
                $allOutputVarPath[] = array($value => $jobRetParam[$i]);
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

The `$allOutputVar` comes from a Database the `$key == 4` is where the `$value`holds the path that I'm using after that in the `$path` variable in the loop below. The `$jobRetParam[$i]` is explained just under the "**Update**" word, each `$value` gets his set of results.

I have a lot of code but at the end it comes to this when encoding to `Json`:

```
foreach ($allOutputVarPath as $key => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $path => $fileContent) {
            $writeSuccess = wrtieToHDD($path, "w", $fileContent);
        }
}
```

> Hier is an example of a `$path => $fileContent` that I use as an input in the `wrtieToHDD()` function where I encode the `$fileContent` as `Json`.
>
> - `$path`: [.../sorted2.txt]
> - `$fileContent`: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 10 [3] => 11 [4] => 12 [5] => 14 [6] => 14 [7] => 15 [8] => 16 [9] => 16 [10] => 17 [11] => 18 [12] => 18 [13] => 18 [14] => 19 [15] => 19 [16] => 20 [17] => 21 [18] => 23 [19] => 24 [20] => 24 [21] => 25 [22] => 25 [23] => 26 [24] => 28 [25] => 28 [26] => 29 [27] => 29 [28] => 32 [29] => 32 [30] => 32 [31] => 33 [32] => 33 [33] => 34 [34] => 35 [35] => 36 [36] => 37 [37] => 38 [38] => 38 [39] => 4 [40] => 4 [41] => 42 [42] => 43 [43] => 46 [44] => 46 [45] => 47 [46] => 47 [47] => 48 [48] => 5 [49] => 57 [50] => 58 [51] => 6 [52] => 61 [53] => 63 [54] => 63 [55] => 64 [56] => 66 [57] => 67 [58] => 68 [59] => 68 [60] => 71 [61] => 72 [62] => 73 [63] => 74 [64] => 76 [65] => 79 [66] => 79 [67] => 8 [68] => 8 [69] => 80 [70] => 80 [71] => 81 [72] => 81 [73] => 82 [74] => 85 [75] => 85 [76] => 86 [77] => 91 [78] => 92 [79] => 92 [80] => 94 [81] => 96 [82] => 96 [83] => 97 [84] => 97 [85] => 98 )

And the `wrtieToHDD()` function:

```
function wrtieToHDD ($destination, $fopenMode, $content) {
    $handle = fopen($destination, $fopenMode);

    // check if $content is an array
    if (gettype($content) == "array" or "object") {

        // encode as json
        $content = json_encode($content);
    }

    // write into file
    $writeContent = FALSE;
    if (flock($handle, LOCK_EX)) { // exclusiv lock
        fwrite($handle, $content);
        fflush($handle); // clear the output buffer bevor the lock free
        flock($handle, LOCK_UN); // free lock
        $writeContent = TRUE;
    }

    fclose($handle);
    return $writeContent;
}
```

Comment: It's sorting by alphas. You need to load the array with numbers if you want it sorted numerically. Show us the code where you're building the array in PHP just before encoding it.

Comment: @JonathanM I posted an Update

Comment: @JonathanM Do you see anything there that causes the strange output?

Comment: Are you reading the `$fileContent` from a file located at `$path`? If so, it's pulling it in as text, not numeric values. Show where you're assigning values to `$allOutputVarPath`, please.

Comment: @JonathanM I'm writing the `$fileContent` Json encoded to a file located in `$path` variable, after that I'm using JSON.parse() to read from the file and to create an array which I use as an input in a different JavaScript function (the bubleSort()). 
The array in the `$fileContent` comes from another page, it's an output of a JavaScript code being sent using POST to the site with the code above.

Comment: Please show where you're assigning value to `$allOutputVarPath`

Comment: @JonathanM I have updated my update post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should take care of it.

Change:

```
$allOutputVarPath[] = array($value => $jobRetParam[$i]);
```

To:

```
$allOutputVarPath[] = array($value => (int)$jobRetParam[$i]);
```

In your original version, the numbers are coming back into `$_REQUEST['results']` as string representations of the values. If you were ever to do an arithmetic operation on one of the strings, PHP would convert the string to a number on the fly to deal properly with it.

However, in this case, each is just eventually converted to JSON, and the JSON conversion doesn't know that it should be numeric, so it leaves it as a string.

The `(int)` *casts* the string to an integer. See here for more detail:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the `$jobRetParam = $_REQUEST['results'];`. The `$_REQUEST` is passed through `urldecode()` so all its members are strings instead of numbers. When you assign strings to `$allOutputVarPath` of course you're going to get string in your json that messes with your sorting.

You can either use `intval()` as in `$allOutputVarPath[] = array($value => intval($jobRetParam[$i]));` or convert string to number in javascript when sorting.